# Error YouTubePlayerView XML

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-xml

I'm trying to put a YouTubePlayerView inside my Adapter but I didn't have success.

I don't want to call a new Intent. I want to show the video inside my app.

I put the YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar inside my folder libs and look at the project properties and it's all ok (I followed this [tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/using-googles-youtube-api-in-your-android-apps/))

Here's is my XML code and the log.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_contentExercicios_LayoutVideoGif"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView 
            android:id="@+id/vv_contentExercicios_YoutubeVideo"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_contentExercicios_GifExercicio"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" >
        </ImageView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

```
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.timo.atlas/br.com.timo.atlas.PrincipalActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #121: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #121: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at br.com.timo.atlas.adapters.ExerciciosAdapter.getView(ExerciciosAdapter.java:107)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at br.com.timo.atlas.adapters.MusculoAdapter.getView(MusculoAdapter.java:185)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at br.com.timo.atlas.PrincipalActivity.onCreate(PrincipalActivity.java:275)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     ... 11 more
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     ... 23 more
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.(Unknown Source)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.(Unknown Source)
10-29 13:03:42.598: E/AndroidRuntime(4513):     ... 26 more
```

P.S.: I was reading the Youtube API documentation and it said that it is necessary an activity extends a YouTubeBaseActivity to use an YouTubePlayerView so I know I will need some way to create the YouTubePlayerView inside my BaseAdapter.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method onBindViewHolder() in your adapter should look like this...

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoInfoHolder holder, final int position) {


    final YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener  onThumbnailLoadedListener = new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
            youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(Resources.KEY, new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VideoID[position]);
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoadedListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
             //write something for failure
        }
    });
}
```

and in your viewHolder class in adapter-> implement onclick listener like this...

```
public class VideoInfoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView;
    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
    protected ImageView playButton;

    public VideoInfoHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        playButton=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnYoutube_player);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
        youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) ctx, Resources.KEY, VideoID[getLayoutPosition()]);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And very first replace your widget from

```
`<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView 
            android:id="@+id/vv_contentExercicios_YoutubeVideo"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />`
```

to

```
`<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to extend YouTubeBaseActivity or you can use YouTubePlayerSupportFragment and FrameActivity from android.support.v4.

```
<fragment
  android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
  android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

YouTube doesn't allow more than one YouTube player view in an activity.
I don't know your requirement but you can use a viewpager with fragments and inside A fragment you can dynamically add youtubefragment to your fragment using childfragmentmanager.

Answer (score 0):

In your java file `ex.  MainActivity.java`
try to 
replace `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`
with    `public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity`